# file content as a command input on linux

Tags: linux, command

For example, I have a file **a.txt** with the content "*123456*" which is my root's password. I input the command "**su**", then it displays "*Password:* " to prompt me to input my password.

How can I regard the file content (i.e. "123456") as the input of the password?

Thanks for all of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the command expects something on the command line, you can use a syntax like

```
ls -ll `cat file_list.txt`
```

but if you just want to automate some commands, maybe you can consider to give a look at [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/)

In your specific case, I suppose the better solution is to go with expect, since **su** don't seems to expect a password as a command line argument